# Without touching gitlab runner, can I add a default docker image based on the tag, using only yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Take

```
test-java:
  stage: test
  image: gradle:6.3.0-jdk11
  script:
    - gradle test
  tags:
    - linux
```

Is something like this possible:

```
tags:
   linux:
      image:  gradle:6.3.0-jdk11
test-java:
  stage: test
  script:
    - gradle test
  tags:
    - linux
```

Thanks in advance and pardon me if this question was already asked, could not find it while searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help to understand why you would want to do this. Tags are primarily used to select a specific runner and not the image (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags). If you only want to specify your image once, you could just use the image keyword at the root level:

```
image:  gradle:6.3.0-jdk11

stages:
  - test
    
test_java:
  stage: test
  script:
    - gradle test
```

Optional, you can make use of variables:

```
variables:
  linux: gradle:6.3.0-jdk11

stages:
  - test
    
test_java:
  stage: test
  image: $linux
  script:
    - gradle test
```

Comment: Hi @JFWenisch, thank you for your reply.  
I need to run the tests on both a windows as a linux environment, but reading you reply, I think I'll go with your variables option!

Thank you